# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: json, angular, json-server

I'm developing one project in which I'm using Angular and JSON server, and I'm getting this error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')**. In the below I've mentioned the code that I've used while developing my project and the the ScreenShot of the Error Message also, please check and help me out. Thanks!

```
<!-- Toolbar to add and search Employees -->
<div class="toolbar ">
    <div class="add-employee">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Employee</button>
    </div>
    <div class="serach-employees">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Employees">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Area to display all the employees -->

<div class="employees">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <span class="text-seconday fs-2 fw-bold fst-italic">There are no employees added!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Bootstrap Modal-->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter Employee Information</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form [formGroup]="employeeForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastname">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Personal Information -->
                        <div class="row mt-5">
                            <div class="col form-heading">
                                <h6 class="text-secondary fst-italic">Personal Information</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="datepicker" class="form-label">BirthDate</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control" formControlName="birthdate">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h6 class="text-seconday">Gender</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" class="form-check-input" formControlName="gender">
                                                <label for="male" class="form-check-label">Male</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" class="form-check-input" formControlName="gender">
                                                <label for="female" class="form-check-label">Female</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col">
                            <select class="form-select" formControlName="education">
                                <option value="default" selected>Select Your Education</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let option of educationOptions;let i=index;" value="{{i}}">{{option|titlecase}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="profile" class="form-label">Profile Photo</label>
                            <input type="file" id="profile" class="form-control" #fileinput>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col form-heading">
                            <h6 class="text-secondary fst-italic">Job Information</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" formControlName="company">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" placeholder="Job Exeperience (yrs)" class="form-control" formControlName="jobExperience">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" placeholder="Salary (in LPA)" class="form-control" formControlName="salary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="addEmployee()">Insert Details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my Service File**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../Model/Employee.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  baseurl=  'http://localhost:3000/posts'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees()
  {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseurl);
  }

  postEmployee(employee:Employee)
  {
    return this.http.post<Employee>(this.baseurl,employee)
  }

  deleteEmployee(id:string)
  {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseurl+'/'+id);
  }
}
```

**This is my TS File**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/Model/Employee.model';
import { EmployeeServiceService } from 'src/app/Services/employee-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:any;
  @ViewChild('addEmployeeButton') addEmployeeButton: any;
  
  educationOptions=[
    '10th Passed',
    '12th Passed',
    'Graduation',
    'Post Graduation'
  ];

  employeeForm:FormGroup;
  employees:Employee[];
  employeesToDisplay:Employee[];
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private service:EmployeeServiceService) {
    this.employeeForm=fb.group({});
    this.employees=[];
    this.employeesToDisplay=this.employees;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeForm=this.fb.group({
      firstname:this.fb.control(''),
      lastname:this.fb.control(''),
      birthdate:this.fb.control(''),
      gender:this.fb.control(''),
      education:this.fb.control('default'),
      company:this.fb.control(''),
      jobExperience:this.fb.control(''),
      salary:this.fb.control(''),
    });

    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    } );
    console.log(this.addEmployee());
  }

  //#region FormControls
  public  get FirstName():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('firstname') as FormControl
  }
  public  get LastName():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('listname') as FormControl
  }
    public  get BirthDate():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('birthdate') as FormControl
  }
  public  get Gender():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('gender') as FormControl
  }
  public  get Education():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('education') as FormControl
  }
    public  get Company():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('company') as FormControl
  }
  public  get Job():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('jobExperience') as FormControl
  }
  public  get Salary():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('salary') as FormControl
  }

  //#endregion FormContorls

  clearForm(){
    this.FirstName.setValue('');
    this.LastName.setValue('');
    this.BirthDate.setValue('');
    this.Gender.setValue('');
    this.Education.setValue('');
    this.Company.setValue('');
    this.Job.setValue('');
    this.Salary.setValue('');
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.value='';
  }

  addEmployee() {
    let employee: Employee = {
      firstname: this.FirstName.value,
      lastname: this.LastName.value,
      birthdate: this.BirthDate.value,
      gender: this.Gender.value,
      education: this.educationOptions[parseInt(this.Education.value)],
      company: this.Company.value,
      jobExperience: this.Job.value,
      salary: this.Salary.value,
      profile: this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0]?.name,
    };
    this.service.postEmployee(employee).subscribe((res) => {
      this.employees.unshift(res);
      this.clearForm();
    });
  }
}
```

**Model File**

```
export class Employee{
    id?:number=0;
    firstname:string='';
    lastname:string='';
    birthdate:string='';
    gender:string='';
    education:string='';
    company:string='';
    jobExperience:number=0;
    salary:number=0;
    profile:string='';
}
```

I tried checking the logic and the places it might have the error, but still the hard luck. Below I've mentioned the ScreenShot of the error for the reference, kindly have a look.

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLWM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
public  get LastName():FormControl{
    return this.employeeForm.get('listname') as FormControl
}
```

Should be `get('lastname')`

Comment: Thanks, but got another. "
        
       ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')"

Please help me in this.

Comment: I've updated the typo error in @ViewChild('') and still showing the same.